# Variable parts formula for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, formula, lm

In this part of my Shiny app, I'll do a 'linear model' (`lm()`) regression, using the variables the user selects. There are three inputs:

1. `input$lmTrendFun` is a `selectInput()`, with the options `c("Linear", "Exponential", "Logarithmic", "Quadratic", "Cubic")`:

   ```
   selectInput("lmTrendFun", "Select the model for your trend line.", 
               choices = c("Linear", "Exponential", "Logarithmic", "Quadratic", "Cubic"))
   ```
2. The second input is `input$lmDep`, and it's a `selectInput()` too. I created a `updateSelectInput` first inside an `observe()` reactive function, so the choices are the column names from the imported `tibble`.
3. The third input is `input$lmInd` and it's a `checkboxGroupInput()`, the choices being all the column names other than the one that's already  the `input$lmInd`.

From that I want this output: the `lm()` (or rather, `summary.lm()` or `summary(lm())`) result for those variables. If I knew which they were, it would be simple:

```
if(input$lmTrendFun == "Linear"){
    form <- yname ~ x1 + x2
}else if(input$lmTrendFun == "Exponential"){
    form <- yname~ exp(x1) + exp(x2)
}else if(input$lmTrendFun == "Logarithmic"){
    form <- yname~ log(x1) + log(x2)
}else if(input$lmTrendFun == "Quadratic"){
    form <- yname ~ poly(x1, 2) + poly(x2, 2)
}else if(input$lmTrendFun == "Cubic"){
    form <- y ~ poly(x1, 3) + poly(x2, 3)
}

[...]
lm(form, data = .)
```

where the data (`.`) has the columns `yname`, `x1` and `x2`.

However, I don't. So I believe I need some more generic function that can create the formula. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
formulizer <- function() as.formula(paste0( input$lmDep, "~", switch(input$lmTrendFun, 
            Linear = paste0(input$lmInd, collapse=" + "),
            Logarithmic =  paste0("exp(", input$lmInd,")", collapse=" + "),
            Quadratic =  paste0("poly(", input$lmInd,", 2)", collapse=" + "),
            Cubic =  paste0("poly(", input$lmInd,", 3)", collapse=" + ") )))
```

```
> input <- list(lmInd=paste0("V", 1:5), lmTrendFun="Linear", lmDep="Vp")
> formulaizer()
Vp ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5
<environment: 0x7fad1cf63d48>
> input <- list(lmInd=paste0("V", 1:5), lmTrendFun="Logarithmic", lmDep="Vp")
> formulizer()
Vp ~ exp(V1) + exp(V2) + exp(V3) + exp(V4) + exp(V5)
<environment: 0x7fad01e694d0>
> input <- list(lmInd=paste0("V", 1:5), lmTrendFun="Quadratic", lmDep="Vp")
> formulizer()
Vp ~ poly(V1, 2) + poly(V2, 2) + poly(V3, 2) + poly(V4, 2) + 
    poly(V5, 2)
<environment: 0x7fad01f51d20>
> input <- list(lmInd=paste0("V", 1:5), lmTrendFun="Cubic", lmDep="Vp")
> formulizer()
Vp ~ poly(V1, 3) + poly(V2, 3) + poly(V3, 3) + poly(V4, 3) + 
    poly(V5, 3)
<environment: 0x7fad01f59690>
```

Comment: Wow! That actually improves the code I had! I thought there would be a function that improved that sequence of ìf`s and `else`s, but didn't know what it was... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider `switch` with vectorized `paste0` to build terms with transformations and then pass terms into `reformulate`. Adjust below inputs to actual Shiny variables:

```r
dep_term <- ...
ind_terms <- ...

form <- switch(input$lmTrendFun,
                Linear = reformulate(ind_terms, response="yname"),
                Exponential = reformulate(paste0("exp(", ind_terms, ")"), response=dep_term),
                Logarithmic = reformulate(paste0("log(", ind_terms, ")"), response=dep_term),
                Quadratic = reformulate(paste0("poly(", ind_terms, ", 2)"), response=dep_term),
                Cubic = reformulate(paste0("poly(", ind_terms, ", 3)"), response=dep_term)
        )
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/VICM74263)</kbd>